# Expressing that there was no need to worry

Tags: word-usage, past-tense, auxiliary-verbs, present-participles

Which is correct?

> - All the work was completed on time, so you need not **to worry**
> - All the work was completed on time, so you need not **have worried**
> - All the work was completed on time, so you did not **need worry**
> - All the work was completed on time, so you need not **worrying**

Answer (score 1):

Using "need" like that is a little old-fashioned, but still widely used. It comes off as very proper/fancy.

Since you say in the title that you want to tell the person that there was no need to (ever) worry, you need the past tense.

The most obvious and native-sounding way of saying this to me would be:

> "All the work was completed on time, so you had nothing to worry about."

It is a bit idiomatic as "nothing to worry about" is a very common phrase. It sounds very natural.

If you want to use "need" specifically, I would say:

> "All the work was completed on time, so there was no need to worry"

Saying "he need not worry" is perfectly grammatical and easy to understand. It just sounds very formal. Most people would just say "he doesn't need to worry." You can read more about that [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29409/why-use-need-not-instead-of-do-not-need-to).

There is maybe some syntactically valid way of phrasing it like "so you need not to have worried" but it sounds very awkward to me, and it takes some effort to understand someone saying that.